# Homology group of product manifold of tori?

Tags: homology-cohomology

What is the homology group $H_k(T^2 x T^2 x T^2, \mathbb{Z})$? The homology group (which I think of as the number of equivalence classes of $k$-cycles, but maybe that is wrong) for the  $n$-torus is $\mathbb{Z}=\binom n k$, but I don't know if the same is true here.

Comment: This is a $6$-torus, so...?

Comment: Did you learn the Kunneth formula?